# How do I programmatically find out whether or not a music file has copyright protection?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I simply need to know because files with copyright protection can NOT BE MODIFIED at all from what I am finding out. I tried Googling this problem for a while. I didn't come up with much as far as how iOS works.

Comment: "files with copyright protection can NOT BE MODIFIED at all". *If* that is true, just try to modify it. If it works, it is not protected...

Comment: In the general case you can't, since you could easily have a file which contains copyrighted music but is not DRM encoded or otherwise identified.  Absence of an explicit copyright notice does not mean that the material is not copyrighted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume what you really want to know is how to tell whether the file itself indicates it is copyright protected, since there is no easy way to determine whether something is copyrighted just by looking at it (which, incidentally, is one of the reasons sites like Youtube require the copyright holder to complain about a [DMCA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Millennium_Copyright_Act) violation most of the time).

Unfortunately, what you're asking for depends largely upon the file format, not simply because the information will be in different places, but also because some audio formats don't have a place for that information at all.

Additionally, it's worth pointing out that copyright material may be used / modified if such use falls under "[fair use](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fair_use)". Non-profit uses, parodies, educational films, etc. are protected. If your application is protected, you may not need to worry about the limitations mentioned above. If your application *isn't* protected, you'll need to give specifics about file format, and you may also want to (at minimum) ask an attorney what you're required to do to ensure you've legally done enough.